# Norm for an operator related to the Christoffel-Darboux kernel

Tags: normed-spaces, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $p_0, p_1, \ldots$ be the orthonormal polynomials for the measure $\mu$ on the interval $[a,b]$. That is, $\displaystyle \int_a^b p_i(x)p_j(x) d\mu(x) = \delta_{i,j}$ with $\delta_{i,j}$ the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). Define the Christoffel-Darboux kernel

$$K_n(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^n p_j(x)p_j(y)$$

And define the operator

$$K_n(f; x) = \int_a^b f(y)K_n(x,y) d\mu(y)$$

I would like to find the two operator norms $||K_n||_{\infty}$ and $||K_n||_2$.

In both cases one can take $f(y)$ outside of the integral and bound it by $||f||_{\infty} \le \mu([a,b])^{1/2}||f||_2$ so we are left with bounding the norm of $\int_a^b K_n(x,y) d\mu(y)$.

To find the latter norm, we might want to use the [Christoffel-Darboux formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel%E2%80%93Darboux_formula) which states that, for some constant $a_n$,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} p_j(x)p_j(y) = a_{n} \frac{p_{n+1}(x)p_{n}(y) - p_{n+1}(y)p_{n}(x)}{x - y}$$

And this holds for $x \neq y$. For $x = y$ we have

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} p_j(x)p_j(y) = a_n \left(p'_{n+1}(x)p_n(x) - p_{n+1}(x)p'_n(x) \right)$$

However, I do not know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you meant $\|f\|_2\le\mu([a,b])^{1/2}\|f\|_\infty$.  But in any case, I'm not sure this is needed.

**The $L^2$ case:**

Observe that $\{p_n\}_0^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([a,b],\mu)$.  Let $(,)$ be the inner product.  By Bessel's inequality, we have $\sum_0^\infty|(f,p_i)|^2\le\|f\|^2_2$, so
$$
\|K_n(f)\|_2^2=\sum_{i=0}^n|(f,p_i)|^2\le\sum_{i=0}^\infty|(f,p_i)|^2\le\|f\|^2_2,
$$
i.e. $\|K_n\|_{L^2\to L^2}\le 1$.  But $K_n(p_0)=p_0$, so $\|K_n\|_{L^2\to L^2}=1$.

**The $L^\infty$ case:**

It is easy to see that
$$
\|K_n\|_{L^\infty\to L^\infty}\le \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\int_a^b|K_n(x,y)|d\mu(y).
$$
In fact, this is an equality.  Fix $x\in[a,b]$ and choose $f(y)=\text{sgn}\, K_n(x,y)$.  Then $K_n(f;x)=\int_a^b|K_n(x,y)|d\mu(y)$, so by continuity, $\|K_n(f)\|_\infty\ge \int_a^b|K_n(x,y)|d\mu(y)$.  Taking the supremum over $[a,b]$ gives the result.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your correction and your answer. It seems correct and clear, so I will accept it. However, the $L^{\infty}$ case does not feel very satisfying since it is not obvious which $x$ maximizes the integral and what the value then is. Is there no way to work this out further?

Comment: You can find a more explicit upper bound, but I don't know a more explicit lower bound than $\|K_n\|_{L^\infty\to L^\infty}\ge 1$ (which follows from $K_n(p_0)=p_0$).  Using Holder's inequality, $\|K_n(x,.)\|_1^2\le\mu([a,b])\|K_n(x,.)\|_2^2$, but the latter is just $S(x):=\sum_0^np_i(x)^2$, so $\|K_n\|_{L^\infty\to L^\infty}^2\le \mu([a,b])\|S\|_\infty$.  If $n=0$, the right hand side is just $1$, so $\|K_0\|_{\infty\to\infty}=1$, i.e the upper and lower bounds are sharp.

Comment: Cheers!          $\text{}$